# How to implement screen sharing option WebRTC using Kurento media server

Tags: webrtc, kurento

we are trying to implement the screen sharing option in WebRTC using the Kurento media sever.
can any one share me the reference.

Comment: Is there a specific question you have after reviewing the [Kurento documentation](https://www.kurento.org/documentation)? I suggest you edit your question with a specific question about your particular attempts / implementation / error messages.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to use is this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getDisplayMedia

getUserMedia is normally used to get the Stream of the Webcam of the User. GetDisplayMedia is for the screen. Test it here: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing/#11158460609616426

You will have to:

- Replace the media track of the webcam with the screenshare stream when user starts screensharing, or
- you add a second stream to Kurento (=new WebRTCEndpoint) that you will have to stream to other participants as well

For both there is no tutorial or example, but this should help.